# Getting "Error: read ECONNRESET" on reseting and launching the app

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am getting the following error on resetting the app `[driver.resetApp()]` and on launching the app on Appium (version: 1.4.16.1). I am using Java.

### Eclispe console

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
>   (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.86)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 2.08 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
>   System info: host: 'IN2084073W1', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
>   *** Element info: {Using=id, value=password}
>   Session ID: 2968b7e9-948e-4b75-94ed-838d10a08c82
>   Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, app=C:/apk/appname.apk, javascriptEnabled=true, appActivity=.MainActivity, browserName=, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={newCommandTimeout=120, app=C:/apk/surveyorapp.apk, platformVersion=5.1, deviceName=TA93303Q2F, platformName=Android, appActivity=.MainActivity, browserName=, appPackage=com.axa.surveyorapp}, locationContextEnabled=false, appPackage=com.axa.surveyorapp, newCommandTimeout=120, platformVersion=5.1, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=TA93303Q2F, platformName=Android, webStorageEnabled=false, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]

### Appium Log

> error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET
>   error: Chromedriver: Chromedriver exited unexpectedly with code 3221225477, signal null
>   info: Chromedriver: Changed state to 'stopped'
>   warn: Chromedriver for context WEBVIEW_com.clientname.appname stopped   unexpectedly
>   error: Chromedriver quit unexpectedly during session

---

### Update

Thanks for the update Emna. I have tried your option.

Can you please let me know how exactly I need to add this. I am using AndroidDriver not AppiumDriver. I have tried with both, but I'm getting below error.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
 (AppiumDriver)driver.resetApp();
```

Instead of :

```
    driver.resetApp();
```

You can have a look into this link:  [Appium java-client](https://github.com/appium/java-client)
and use [this link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) also to download ;)

Comment: Not working Emna.. See the original question for the error i am getting

Comment: Ohh, it was just a suggestion i'm not sure that this is the perfect solution, did you add the jar java client ? so that (AppiumDriver) can be ok ?

Comment: Yes,, I am having all the pre-requisite to run appium